# Auto 777 permissions needs to set under folder when files are receiving

Tags: permissions

I have a folder /user/application/feed (feed folder)

I am getting files to feed folder from other source, only Read and Write Permissions to Group Level while receiving. I need to set 777 automatic when ever any files will come under feed.

Is there any command we can set to feed folder to maintain Auto 777 while files coming to feed folder

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want files added to /user/application/feed to automatically receive the permissions 777. Firstly, make the permissions of the folder 777 with

```
chmod 777 /user/application/feed
```

> It's also important to remember that access to these 777 files will
>   still be restricted by each of the parent directories (e.g. if you
>   have restrictive permissions on `/user/application` then some users
>   may not be able to see your files.

You can then use ACL's to ensure that all newly created files inherit the permissions of the parent directory. For an overview of this process you can see this question: https://superuser.com/questions/151911/how-to-make-new-file-permission-inherit-from-the-parent-directory

In brief, you should try:

```
setfacl -d -m u::rwx /user/application/feed/
setfacl -d -m g::rwx /user/application/feed/
setfacl -d -m o::rwx /user/application/feed/
```

If these commands fail, it may be because ACLs are disabled for your volume. In this case you can enable them in `/etc/fstab`